# excel formula with sum offset and match doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

below you can find an image off my situation.

I need to add the values of the totals from the subs and the result needs to come in the cell next to *"subtotaal:"* in the main block. But here is the catch, the number of subs are not always the same. That also means the cells are variable. in this example there are only 2 subs, but in the real sheet there can be 20 subs. below the first main there is another main with his subs. in this main block i need to use the same formula again, and so on.

i've tried with this formula, but it contains an error and i don't know how to fix it.

```
=SUM(OFFSET($K4,0,0,MATCH("subtotaal:",$j4:$j1000,-1),1))
```

i hope you guys can help me.

[image: my situation]

Comment: In your formula you should have ',' instead ';'. The error you get is in syntax or in the calculation?

Comment: In your example on main you want at the subtotaal to add 4717.08+3450? or add there the subtotaal of main 2?

Comment: add the total of 4717.08+3450

Comment: okay i've changed the , to ; and the formula doesn't have a error anymore, but i get the result € _. So thanks already that was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -1 you've got in the match formula is setting the lookup type to be less than or equal.

The -1 wants to be outside the match function, to make sure that the range doesn't include the cell it's being called from, which is what is creating the circular reference error you've been getting.

Try this instead:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($K4,0,0,MATCH("subtotaal:",$j4:$j1000,0)-1,1))
```